# DNS Lookup for localhsot failed. No such host is known

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

i did a break point on the method but it never goes there and also if paste the url in the web browser and hit enter and this is what i get in Firebug:

```
ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.
```

EDIT:

indeed that was typo, after correcting it and i still have no response, in FF i see the response

```
GET GetCustomer?method=jsonp1299253547713
http://localhost:2344/service1.svc/GetCustomer?method=jsonp1299253547713

Aborted

localhost:2344

?
```

what may be wrong ?

**END EDIT**

i have a created wcf services using json with padding (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898(v=vs.90).aspx)

i have the code below that i am using to call the service, and this code is in html page withint th same project that i have created the wcf service.

```
$("#btn").click(function (event) {

            $.getJSON('http://localhsot:2344/Service1.svc/GetCurrentUser?method=?', { },
            function (data) {
                debugger
                alert(data);
            });
            //return false;
        });
```

getting this error:

**DNS Lookup for localhsot failed. No such host is known**

Comment: um, maybe try **localhost**, not localhsot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming:

`localhsot` => `localhost`

Comment: @Abu Hamzah, is the web method invoked? If you put a breakpoint inside is it hit? Is the web service started? What happens if you type directly `http://localhost:2344` inside the address bar?

Comment: @Abu Hamzah, it seems that you didn't start the web service. Make sure that you start the web project containing the WCF service. In Visual Studio right click on it and select Set as Startup Project... then hit Ctrl+F5 to run it. Once you ensure that the service is running (accessible in your browser) you could test your application.

Answer (score 0):

You spelled localhost wrong.  Look at your url and fix the spelling error.